# Google Analytics: This property is no longer processing new data. Save your property data before it's deleted

Tags: google, google-analytics

I see this when I login to GA:

> This property is no longer processing new data. Save your property
> data before it's deleted.
>
> Finish migrating to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) before July 1, 2024 using
> the Setup Assistant, if you haven't already done so. To maintain
> access to data from this property, you should download your data now.

I'm not running any websites since few years ago and last time I used Google Analytics was also years ago... but I don't want to lose access to my historical data of my websites in GA. I'm a little confused by Google's help pages. Can someone summarize what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

They have implemented Google Analytics 4 (GA4) as their new engine. All the old tags have ceased processing data but the properties are still available to pull data from.

I believe after July 2024, you won't be able to pull any data out of the property so they recommend getting all that you can put of the property before then.

You should get all the key data that is critical to your site (views, events, conversions) in order to do historical comparisons against your new property.

You will also need to setup a new GA4 tag on your site to collect data with the new engine.

Comment: So old data will be removed???

Comment: At the end of the above mentioned date, yes. You will no longer be able to access Universal data. They have been moving the entire user base to this point for at least 3 years.